# error: undefined reference to.. long list while compiling GTK-3.12.2

Tags: linux, gtk, undefined-reference

Getting 100+ errors like this:

```
./.libs/libgtk-3.so: undefined reference to `g_drive_can_start_degraded'
```

I've provided all the linker flags like `-lglib-2.0 -lfreetype` etc. still I'm getting those errors any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is often Google. Search for `g_drive_can_start_degraded` to find out in which library/project it might be. The first link returns GDrive from GIO: https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GDrive.html

Further down, it says `glib: gio/gdrive.c`

So it seems that this function is part of `glib`. Let's find this library:

```
find /usr/lib* -name "libglib*.so*"
```

If that doesn't show up any hits, try also the usual places like `/lib*` or `/usr/local/lib*`.

For me, it gives this list:

```
/usr/lib/cli/glib-sharp-2.0/libglibsharpglue-2.so
/usr/lib/vmware-installer/2.1.0/lib/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-installer/2.1.0/lib/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0/libglib-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0/libglib-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libglibmm-2.4.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libglibmm-2.4.so.1/libglibmm-2.4.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libglibmm_generate_extra_defs-2.4.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libglibmm_generate_extra_defs-2.4.so.1/libglibmm_generate_extra_defs-2.4.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglibmm-2.4.so.1.3.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglibmm_generate_extra_defs-2.4.so.1.3.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglibmm-2.4.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglibmm_generate_extra_defs-2.4.so.1
```

`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so` looks like the most promising candidate. Let's see what's inside:

```
objdump --dynamic-syms /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so | grep g_drive_can_start_degraded
```

which returns nothing. Maybe I have the wrong version of `glib` (2.x instead of 3.x)?

But further investigation shows that I also have `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0`:

```
> objdump --dynamic-syms /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 | grep  g_drive_can_start_de
000000000003f080 g    DF .text  0000000000000078  Base        g_drive_can_start_degraded
```

Seems like you're missing `-lgio-2.0` somewhere.

If the library didn't define the symbol but would need it, the output would look like this:

```
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000              g_setenv
```

Note the address is 0 and the segment is `*UND*` instead of `.text`.

Note: The order of libraries that you pass to the linker is important! The linker will search each library only once.

Comment: Thank you Sir!!. I've compiled all libraries from source so I have the correct versions of the libraries, but as you told `-lgio-2.0` I've not included it, will include it and try it again. Thanks for such an answer as it not only explain me the error but also helps me how to tackle those errors in future.

Comment: Sir i've solved all the undefined reference errors using your way now I'm just left with two of them `/lib/libatk-bridge-2.0.so: undefined reference to `atspi_is_initialized'
/lib/libatk-bridge-2.0.so: undefined reference to `atspi_set_main_context'
Any thing else?

Comment: You can use `grep -r atspi_is_initialized /usr/lib` to search for all files that contain this symbol. Note that you'll also get libraries which need / input it, so you need to use `objdump` to distinguish between the two.